# nginx proxy only serves part of data Wordpress running on Ngninx

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, proxy, fpm

I have a Wordpress instance running on first nginx server ( Virtual Machine A ) .
I can work with perfectly fine locally, everythings is well resolved and all path are accessed ( like /wp-admin/ , /wp-content/ , /wp-includes/ etc... ) thru my url www.corph.mouradcloud.com

As for now, I am not using SSL, so this a later issue :)

here is the config of my Nginx web instance :

```
        upstream php-wp {
            server            unix:/var/run/mouradcloud.sock;
        }

        server {
            listen            80;
            listen            [::]:80;
            server_name       www.corph.mouradcloud.com;
            root              /var/www/mouradcloud;

                index                     index.php;

                location / {
                        try_files     $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                }

                location = /favicon.ico {
                        log_not_found off;
                        access_log    off;
                }

                location = /robots.txt {
                        allow                    all;
                        log_not_found off;
                        access_log    off;
                }

                location ~ .php$ {
                        include       fastcgi.conf;
                        fastcgi_pass  php-wp;
                }

                location ~* .(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                        expires       max;
                        log_not_found off;
                }
        }
```

I have a second Nginx server that I use as a Proxy with a different URL ( Virtual Machine B ) . 
After a little of google, I noticed that some other parameters need to be added to have the PHP scripts thru proxy either.

here is the proxy nginx file :

```
        server {
                listen         80;
                listen         [::]:80;
                server_name    www.mouradcloud.com;

                location / {
                proxy_pass http://www.corph.mouradcloud.com;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                }

        }
```

Strangely, when a client is connecting using the web browser dbugger the path /wp-content/ , /wp-includes/ are resolved thru :

```
    www.corph.mouradcloud.com
```

instead of

```
    www.mouradcloud.com
```

here is the screenshot of the debugger, we can see that only documents are passing thru the proxy, scripts are rejected while it should not since I am passing every thing thru the proxy in the request..

[image]

My guess is there is some parameters that I am missing.

I tryed to add other location like /wp-includes/ , but I ended up screwing everything ...

I reviewed all the SO thread but noone has an answers so far

Comment: Can you share the nginx access and error logs?

Comment: I found the solution. I answered my question with a detailed config, for people to save time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around I found the solution. It was ... simple... So I will share every part of the config for people to not lose time in the future...

Here is the overall situations [image]

Remember, As for this first try, I will not use SSL with Let's encrypt, I will keep it for later. For now, this is simple http.

On the NGINX Proxy, I create a site with this config file ( /etc/nginx/sites-available/www.mouradcloud.com )

```
    server {
     listen 80;
     server_name www.mouradcloud.com;

    location / {
     proxy_pass http://www.corph.mouradcloud.com;
     sub_filter_once off;
     sub_filter 'www.corph.mouradcloud.com' 'www.mouradcloud.com';
     sub_filter_types *;
     }
    }
```

On the VM Wordpress&Nginx, here is the wp-config.php (/var/www/mouradcloud/wp-config.php ), I did added thos 2 lines :

```
    define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.corph.mouradcloud.com');
    define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.corph.mouradcloud.com');
```

lastly in my WM WOrdpress&Nginx, I did not changed the configuration of my nginx web server and this is still the same ( /etc/nginx/sites-available/www.corph.mouradcloud.com) :

```
        upstream php-wp {
            server            unix:/var/run/mouradcloud.sock;
        }

        server {
            listen            80;
            listen            [::]:80;
            server_name       www.corph.mouradcloud.com;
            root              /var/www/mouradcloud;

                index                     index.php;

                location / {
                        try_files     $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                }

                location = /favicon.ico {
                        log_not_found off;
                        access_log    off;
                }

                location = /robots.txt {
                        allow                    all;
                        log_not_found off;
                        access_log    off;
                }

                location ~ .php$ {
                        include       fastcgi.conf;
                        fastcgi_pass  php-wp;
                }

                location ~* .(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                        expires       max;
                        log_not_found off;
                }
        }
```

Not Http is working I will have a look to https...

Comment: good you got it working. Now your NGINX Proxy is changing the URLs in the response. I am not sure if it helps but if you want i can share the sqls for updating urls in the wp database. With this the sub_module is not needed anymore.

Comment: Yeas please do so ! it will be helpfull !

Comment: `SELECT * FROM wp_posts where post_content LIKE %https://www.mouradcloud.com%";
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'www.mouradcloud.com','www.corph.mouradcloud.com');` Do the same for `wp_options` and `wp_postmeta`

Comment: Thank you ! I was not thinking about future articule so this is very time saving !